# How to display SSRS Reports in Web Application using .Net 6.0?

Tags: reporting-services, .net-6.0, ssrs-2019

I am creating a web based application which will be displaying pre-developed reports on SSRS server. This application to be developed in .Net 6.0 with C#.

Please do share sample source on how can I do it without using any third party tools.

Comment: Still awaiting a response, .Net 7.0 is about to release, the expected solution should not be using any third party tool.